# Riak and Ruby: Ripple not return valid entries

Tags: ruby, riak, ripple

I want use riak with my sinatra application.
I'm using gem ripple, describe simple model and simple form for store data.
Then I want to show all saved entries, using "Article.all" all good, but when i store new entry and refresh page - list of entryies not updates until I restart my application.
I'm trying irb, trying sinatra\reloader, but nothing...

Then, I post new entry, it's momentaly appear in default riak rest interface, and when use riack-client directly all good.

```
require 'ripple'
require 'sinatra'

class Article
  include Ripple::Document
  property :title, String
  property :body, String
end

get '/' do
  @articles = Article.all
  erb :articles
end

post '/' do
  article = Article.new(:title => params[:title], :body => params[:body])
  article.save
end
```

Answer (score 1):

All is a costly operation in Riak and does not work. If u use the latest version of the Gem for github you will get a error stating the same.

Comment: but, using riak-client directly, with Riak::MapReduce.new return what I want. It's not riak problem I think, specific behavior of ripple gem...

Comment: If it's costly, it should be removed, IMO.

Comment: @Zuzuka have you filed an issue on github?

Comment: Thats how the database is designed it isnt a bug.